# Matlab - Stack Data Structure

Tags: matlab

Can I have a stack data structure in matlab?

For example a stack of integers where I can push elements in it like `stack.push(i)`, get elements out of it like `i = stack.pop()` and check out if it is empty `stack.isempty()`.

Comment: MATLAB has 'full' OOP capabilities. Just write your stack class. See documentation for MATLAB OOP: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/ug_intropage.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I do not think MATLAB has one even in the newer versions. But you can use Java, it is a "first class citizen" in MATLAB, it would work perfectly with integers as you need it. See also [queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142190/is-there-a-queue-in-matlab) and [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413860/matlab-linked-list) related questions.

Just write in MATLAB `stack=java.util.Stack()` and then you can [call methods on it](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) as in your question `stack.push(i)`, ecc.

Comment: Just be very careful with data type conversions.

Comment: @Andrey This just bit me - I pushed a row vector to a stack and when I popped it, it came out as a column vector.

Answer (score 5):

You can roll your own or you can use someone else's, like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28922-list-queue-stack).

A very simple homemade stack would be an array with a count, the count pointing to the topmost item.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Java one in MATLAB and honestly it is very slow. It's much better to do what @skurmedel said, like so:

```
Ptr = 1;
Stack(ptr,:) = [x,y];
Ptr = ptr + 1;
```

And to simulate `pop`:

```
A = stack(ptr,1);
B = stack(ptr,2);
Ptr = ptr - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful submission in FileExchange:

- [list, queue, stack](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28922-list-queue-stack)

Answer (score 0):

Please use MATLAB arrays as is. They are 100 times faster than using any java util. Write the extra logic to make the array work like a stack.

From personal experience just try to re-write your algorithm to use MATLAB array.