# How to keep chopping the tail of an array (leading to an empty set)

Tags: arrays, matlab

Say `A=[1,3];`.
I want to keep chopping the tail of `A`, except that MALAB does not have a "`A.pop()`"

I tried to write a code like

```
for i=m:-1:1;

A=A(1:i-1);  
end
```

but MATLAB says "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
logicals."

Comment: You can also index the end of the vector using `end`, as in A = A(1:end-1).

Comment: Nominally you just want to say A(end) = [ ]; each time through the loop.  However note, that particularly for large vectors, this can be a very inefficient thing to do.  MATLAB will reallocate memory for the matrix each time through the loop (with the new memory being enough to store one less element than that previous memory), and copy the remaining elements into the new memory, then free the old memory.

Comment: Do you need a stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163920/matlab-stack-data-structure ?

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for a [generic approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722) to deal with this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
if length(A) > 1
    A = A(1:length(A)-1)
else
    A = []
end
```

Comment: Thanhs. Hopefully matlab will come up with some more elegant function some day

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this I guess:

```
if length(A) > 1
    A(end:end) = []
else
    A = []
end
```