# Efficient Way to Generate Vector of Points Used in Recursive Scheme

Tags: matlab, recursion, pass-by-reference, octave

I am implementing the adaptive Simpsons method in Matlab recursively. I wish to store all of the points where function evaluations take place to generate a histogram after integrating. I currently have:

```
function [S, points] = adsimp(f, a, b, fv, tol, level, points)
...
d = (a+b)*0.25;
e = (a+b)*0.75;
points = [points, d, e];
...
```

Thus, for every function call, I am increasing the length of `points` by two. My understanding of Matlab's function input/output scheme is poor. I'd like to know:

1) When the input and output share a variable name, does this use a single variable, or is a local copy made and then returned?

2) If it is a copy, is there a way to pass `points` by reference and preallocate sufficient memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/152). Most MATLAB variables are passed by value (matrices, etc.) unless it is a handle object (function handle, axis handle etc.) A local copy of an input variable is made only if that variable is altered in the function. ie.

```
function y = doTheFunc1(x)
    x(2) = 17;
    y = x;
```

a copy must be made. As opposed to:

```
function y = doTheFunc2(x)
    y = x(1);
```

where no copy need be made inside the function. In other words, MATLAB is a "copy on write" language. I am almost certain this is true regardless what your output variable output name is (ie. this holds even if your output and input are both named `x`).

To answer your second question, look at the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137905/how-to-modify-an-array-in-function). Consider using a [nested function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html?s_tid=doc_12b) or a [handle object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/copying-objects.html).

Comment: Hands to the `func`, do the `func`, rock yo bawwwdddyyyyyy