# How can I delete some variables in NumPy/SciPy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm transiting from Matlab/Octave to NumPy/SciPy. When I use  Matlab in the interactive mode, I used `clear` or `clear [some_variable]` from time to time to remove that variable from memory. For example, before reading some new data to start a new sets of experiments, I used to clear data in Matlab.

How could I do the same thing with NumPy/SciPy?

I did some research, and I found there is a command called `del`, but I heard that `del` actually doesn't clear memory, but the variable disappears from the namespace instead. Am I right?

That being said, what would be the best way to mimic "clear" of Matlab in NumPy/SciPy?

Comment: Use del. If an object isn't referenced, it will be deleted

Comment: I would say "start a new notebook." If that doesn't mean anything to you, you really need to check out ipython notebooks, (http://ipython.org/notebook.html, http://opentechschool.github.io/python-data-intro/core/notebook.html) they will change your life I promise.

Comment: @chanwcom, was your question answered or do you still need help?

Answer (score 6):

`del(obj)` will work, according to the [scipy mail list](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2004-August/015748.html)

If you're working in IPython, then you can also use `%xdel obj`

> ...but I heard that "del" actually doesn't clear memory, but the
>   variable disappears from the namespace. Am I right?

Yes, that's correct. That's what garbage collection is, Python will handle clearing the memory when it makes sense to, you don't need to worry about it, as from your end the variable no longer exists. Your code will behave the same, whether or not garbage collection has occurred yet won't matter, so there's no need for an alternative to `del`.

If you are curious about the differences of Matlab and Pythons garbage collection / memory allocation, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446281/matlabs-garbage-collector) SO thread on it.