# Java LinkedList to matlab array

Tags: java, matlab

In one of the answers to [MATLAB linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413860/matlab-linked-list) the responder suggests using java linked lists, which seems like an excellent solution, but it is not clear what an elegant way is to convert the linkedlist (once constructed) to a matlab cell array (I guess one have a for loop, but that seems a little clunky...

**EDIT**  looks like cell(foo) converts a java array into a matlab array, but that's not quite the same thing...
**EDIT** Enlightenment strikes. If `a` is the LinkedList, then

```
cell(a.toArray(a))
```

does the trick.

Comment: Could you please add your "enlightenment" as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

By popular demand, adding this as an answer: `cell(a.toArray(a))` does what I need.