# how can I store a list of int in matlab using java?

Tags: java, matlab, list

I was trying to use a list in matlab and I found this post:[MATLAB linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413860/matlab-linked-list)

it seems like matlab can use java.
given that I do

```
 a=java.util.linkedList;
 a.add(2);
 a.add(3);
 a.add(5);
```

and I get in a the 3 elements.
The problem comes when I want to remove one of them.
Let's say I want to remove 2.

if I cast

```
 a.remove(2)
```

matlab removes me 5,since it sees 2 as an index.
In java I'd cast the int to Integers,but I can't manage to do it in Matlab (I can't even use the constructor, in java I'd do `linkedList<Integer> a=new linkedList<Integer>()` and then cast 2 to Integer and it should work)

is there any way I can solve this issue?

Comment: I guess I could use a listIterator,search for the element, use previous() and then set next() to next().next() but it seems a bit too much for just removing one entry.

Comment: and the iterator doen't work because I can't check if an element is equal to an int since the element is probably a java object.